Allow job offers?
Should we allow posts that solicit paid assistance on a project (contract or "gig" work)? If yes, should they be redirected to the meta site, left on OR SE with some appropriate tag ("job-offer"?), or moved somewhere else? An example of such a post, which has a variety of flags and down-votes, is Mixed Integer Linear Programming.

Since these types of questions are not useful for any future users, and in the case of the example you referred to, doesn't even have a general question to deem it useful and worthy of keeping on the site, it seems against the policies of the site. I found this kind of similar question on Meta Exchange.
I prefer your approach of referencing places like the OR Discord for that.

Thanks for the link. I was pretty sure that Stack Exchange had faced this issue long ago. I agree that there is no long-term value to these requests, and uncertain short-term value. Maybe what we should have is a wiki "question" listing places one can look for help?

Oh yes. Or now that we have this meta question, maybe we can find some references and linked them in an answer

I suspect it would be easier to find as a wiki "question" on the main site. A lot of people don't know meta exists.
